# DoublyLList C++ // Inserir valor na posição index (com iterator)

Tags: c++, lista, iterator

Minha função para inserir está correta, porém estou tendo leak de memória porque quando fiz debug, `temp->prev->prev` estava apontando para `nullptr` ao invés de apontar para o resto da lista, quando a mesma tiver 3+ elementos.

Obs: O 'endereço' do leak está apontando para `Node* temp = new Node...`

```
void DLList<Type>::insert(DLLIter<Type>& index, const Type & v)
{
    if (index.m_curr == nullptr)
        return;

    Node* temp = new Node(v, index.m_curr->m_prev); // valor, m_prev
    temp->m_next = index.m_curr;

    if (index.m_curr == m_head)
    {
        temp->m_next = m_head;
        m_head = temp;
        index.m_curr = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        index.m_curr->m_prev->m_next = temp;
        index.m_curr = temp;
    }

    ++m_size;
}
```

A função está totalmente correta e o leak está vindo de outro lugar, ou o problema está aí mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Estava faltando algumas conexões entre a lista e o temp.

```
void DLList<Type>::insert(DLLIter<Type>& index, const Type & v)
{
if (index.m_curr == nullptr)
    return;

Node* temp = new Node(v, index.m_curr->m_prev);
temp->m_next = index.m_curr;

if (index.m_curr == m_head)
{
    temp->m_next = m_head;
    m_head = temp;
    index.m_curr = temp;
}
else
{
    index.m_curr->m_prev->m_next = temp;
    temp->m_prev = index.m_curr->m_prev;
    temp->m_next = index.m_curr;
    index.m_curr->m_prev = temp;
    index.m_curr = temp;
}

++m_size;
}
```